# Use the <select> tag to hold Integer to use in arithmetic

Tags: javascript, html, select

I just want to have a simple program that calculates pre-defined values inserted in the select tag and multiplies it to the value of the textbox (which will also be converted to integer) and prints it inside the "prod" textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //num2 is the id of my select tag
    var index = document.getElementById("num2").selectedIndex;

    //num1 is the id of my textbox
    //prod is the id of product textbox
    function mul(){
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("prod").value;
        c.value=(a*b);
    }

</script>
```

I'm going nuts...

Comment: This: `var c = document.getElementById("prod");` not this: `var c = document.getElementById("prod").value;`. Notice I removed the `value` property.

Comment: hmm, the answer still doesn't show. maybe there's another approach to this problem... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bloodyKnuckles is correct, `var b` needs to equal the element, not the value property of the element.

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97b7dbw6/)

Comment: oh wow. thank you so much @joemfb, i'm a noob programmer. still learning the basics. thanks again mate. :)

Comment: It's the little things that get you ;) Best of luck, and keep going! (Also, if the answer is satisfactory, which you click the checkmark next to it to accept it? Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value and use `parseInt()` to conert it to an integer from a string:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4qy4xLL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  //num2 is the id of my select tag
    var index = document.getElementById("num2").selectedIndex;

    //num1 is the id of my textbox
    //prod is the id of product textbox
    function mul() {
    debugger
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("prod");
        c.value = (a * b);
    }
```